# How to fix missing icons in CKeditor after an upgrade or change in package basic, standard, or full

Tags: css, ckeditor, wysiwyg

The problem is that - after upgrading/updating your CKeditor library, or changing packages from basic, standard, or full to another - some button icons are missing and others have the wrong icon, yet functionality of each plug-in still works.

[image: Screenshot of what the problem can look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the editor to appear correct for yourself, you must convince your browser to clear it's cache for the icons.png image. Go to htt://yoursite.com/path/to/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png and then use Ctrl+F5 or Cmd+Shift+R (mac users) to tell your browser to not use the cache and fetch a new one, which will then be stored in the cache.

HOWEVER, you cannot expect your website users to do this. If the image is cached on their machines as well, then they will still be seeing the problem. **The only way to fix this is to change the URL of the image**, which will require replacing the new url in the CSS file (it's the background image for all the buttons).

Comment: That's unfortunately true. To most of the CKEditor files there's a cache busting string attached, but not to `icons.png` because this file is used from stylesheets. Therefore, for now you're right that it's best to upload CKEditor to different path. But we keep this issue in mind and within few months we'll have updated for the CKBuilder to fix this issue.